# O que realmente é Copyright?

Tags: terminologia, licença

Eu uso a licença MIT e ela tem este formato conforme o exemplo em https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT:

```
The MIT License (MIT)
Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>

Permission is ...
```

Também vejo muitos sites adicionando o texto "Copyright" no rodapé, no entanto já ouvi dizer que na verdade esses sites não tem o "copyright", as pessoas colocam isso no rodapé por simplesmente colocar.

Então o que eu gostaria de entender é que digamos que os dados no site não tenham um "licença definida", o copyright no rodapé é quase um erro?

Ou copyright é um termo que eu posso "dizer" quais os direitos de cópia sobre o conteudo ou código?

O que realmente este termo significa?

Comment: "Cópia Certa" ou "Cópia na Certa", rsrsrs. Brincadeira

Comment: Peço que se achou alguma resposta útil aceite uma das respostas.

Answer (score 5):

Legalmente vc tem todos os direitos a respeito de qualquer coisa que vc crie. Então se vc cria um software (ou um livro, ou uma tela, ou qq coisa) ele é automaticamente protegido pela lei e ninguém pode dispor daquele software pra nada a não ser vc mesmo.

Entretanto, algumas pessoas não sabendo disso, acham que podem pegar qualquer código (imagem, livro, etc) na internet e sair usando, por isso alguns autores acham bom colocar o símbolo de copyright associado à obra, lembrando que aquilo tem dono.

Outros entretanto não fazem questão de seus direitos, então colocam licenças (livres ou não) como a creative-commons abrindo mão de alguns de seus direitos automaticamente.

Lembrando que independente de vc colocar um símbolo de copyright, se alguém infringir esses direitos, vc é que terá que provar que o outro infringiu ("ao acusador cabe o ônus da prova"). Por isso alguns autores quando lançam uma obra publicam em algum grande portal ou de alguma outra forma para terem uma prova que aquilo foi criado por eles primeiro.

Há ainda a possibilidade de registro de obra que confere uma formalidade extra ao ato.

Alguns links úteis:

Copyright: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direito_autoral

Licença: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a

Copyleft: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft

Creative Commons: https://br.creativecommons.org/

Licenças GNU: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.pt-br.html

Answer (score 4):

Um website, assim como um livro, um logotipo ou uma revista, é facilmente copiado, sendo fundamental o registro para que sua autoria e propriedade seja respeitada.

O código do website pode ser protegido contratualmente, segundo Dr. Wilson Canesin, advogado, um dos diretores da Jonel Contabilidade,  "O contrato de escrow garante que empresas que adquiriram a licença para utilizar um software possam acessar seu código fonte, sem que haja quebra de copyright".
O conteúdo pode ser protegido, idéias e pensamentos não têm direito a copyright, mas criações aplicadas em meios tangíveis sim, tais como, fotografias, textos, projeto-gráfico do site, para isso deve-se fazer o registro de propriedade.

Assim sendo, geralmente, em blogs, o copyright pode ser direto do provedor como por exemplo o "Blogger", eles tem direitos sobre o conteúdo expresso no site. 
Porém, se você não tiver nenhum registro e ainda assim colocar o Copyright, não vai valer para quase nada, a menos que você consiga provar que é o autor dessas publicações.

Fonte: http://www.significados.com.br/copyright/